# SSL certificate update and renewal in TIBCO BW

Tags: certificate, tibco

I want to set up an automatic update and renewal of ssl certificates in tibco bw, how can this be done in Tibco bw without experiencing any certificate chain errors

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at certnanny

> https://github.com/certnanny/certnanny

it's been around for quite a few years already and stable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about Tibco code, let me assure you , Once deployed Tibco BW will take up certificate from the Cert folder configured for your Admin.

However To keep track of your cert renewal you may use CertNanny or same kind of program. Personally I do not relay on automatic cert renewal especially when it is going to be in the daily check list of support teams.

Answer (score 0):

BW itself do not handle the changing or renewal of certificates. Either you need to change the certificates manually or you need to used third party tool like CertNanny.